# Are the arguments that placebo can be unethical mistaken?

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation, ethics

There seem to be two ideas of placebo - or the treatment received by a placebo group:

1. A "simulation" of a treatment using saline or sugar pill so that subjects in a clinical trial can be randomized, and drug can be administered in a blinded fashion.
2. A "non-treatment" so that the relative effects of a single drug can be isolated.

For example, this real-world evidence group supposes a case where it's unethical to administer a placebo "such as in oncology studies" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86Rgbw_Kw8Y. But I fail to see how that can be the case except if the investigational treatment is extremely harmful.

Two examples: consider a rare form of cancer treatable only by infused chemotherapy. Treatment with chemo gives a median PFS of 3 months and OS of 6 months - in other words, the chemo isn't very good. Suppose I have a new *orally administered* medication which has promising anti-tumor activity in mouse models, and the phase 1A study went well, and I want to inspect anti-tumor activity of my drug as monotherapy in a randomized Phase 2 study.

If my goal is to determine the superiority of my oral drug, it seems that the appropriate choice of placebo is to randomize subjects, say 1:1, to receive either active oral drug and placebo infusion or to receive placebo oral drug and active infusion. On one hand, few people receive chemo without knowing they have it, and infusing saline for an hour is a waste of time. But I'm not exactly sure it's unethical. On the other hand, our objective is to show superiority *to chemotherapy*, so it seems worthless to enroll subjects who receive no anti-cancer drug at all.

1. Which of the two definitions are the clinically accepted standard definition of placebo? (Or what variant thereof?)
2. Are there examples of unethical placebo in an oncology study according to definition 1?
3. Is there actually any value to quantifying option 2, i.e. comparing to a true no-treatment group when there is an established standard-of-care?

EDIT: I realize after posting this we should exclude one obvious example: say attempting surgery on a disease that's pronounced metastatic or unressectable. I see that you can't "blind" a surgery. In any case, some examples would be helpful for me.

Comment: The "blind" surgery is called [sham surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sham_surgery).

Comment: I suppose two ethical objections may be the strongest: (1) Withholding what is now recognized as the best treatment from those who get the new drug, which may turn out to be useless. (2) Any premature administration of the new drug, which may turn out to have some bad effects in spite of "promising" phase 1 results (typically with relatively few subjects). Obviously, these objections do not prevent all clinical trials, but they are the basis for some of the strict regulations on clinical studies.

Comment: A potential perk of a placebo controlled trial would be opening the cody at the end of the study, and informing the patient of her/his actual treatment... this would amount, at least in part, to a n-of-1 trial...

Answer (score 9):

A randomized controlled trial requires that there is a sincere uncertainty about the relative efficacy of the treatments under investigation. The term for this uncertainty is "equipoise."

The feeling that one group is "missing out" on a new treatment is strong, but often not justifiable; many drugs that undergo large trials do not work. An example where "missing out" represented a real harm to patients were the early trials of HIV medications. At the time, there was no treatment for HIV, and it was clearly fatal. Patients with HIV argued that placebo-controlled trials were unethical and were successful in gaining access to experimental medications, which were clearly effective and extended the lives of persons with HIV.

If a reasonable treatment exists for a disease, any new treatment can only be compared to that existing treatment. In such cases, the treatment arms could either be:

1. Usual care versus usual care + new treatment
2. Usual care + placebo versus usual care + new treatment

In your example, you could compare IV chemotherapy + new oral chemotherapy to IV chemotherapy alone. If the efficacy of IV chemotherapy is truly uncertain or potentially harmful, then one could compare the new oral chemotherapy to a placebo.

Comment: It can also be usual care vs new treatment.  Both arms get some Tx.  This is called a "[non-inferiority trial](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms/def/non-inferiority-trial)".

Comment: That is a reasonable group assignment, but non-inferiority refers to a statistical procedure where one only seeks to determine whether treatment A is more harmful than B (ie, A is not inferior to B on the basis of harm).

Comment: Non-inferiority can be used to show that A is 'just as good as' B.  It doesn't have to be *harm*.

Comment: In the medical literature, studies that test whether A is as good as B are termed "equivalency trials." These are rarely performed due to the very large sample sizes required and a lack of interest in whether A is as good as B. Medical device studies are an exception to this rule; the Food and Drug Administration only requires that a new device be non-inferior or equivalent to an existing device.

Comment: I'm a biostatistician, I'm familiar w/ the medical literature. A is as good as B can include A is better than B.  An entity promoting a new intervention of some kind would be perfectly happy if it turns out to be better than an existing approach. They only need to show it's not worse. Non-inferiority is not so exotic. It's covered in intro clinical trials texts such as Friedman et al, *Fundamentals of Clinical Trials*. A pubmed search finds 104 NI trials published last year.  It may help you to read [this explainer](https://trialsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1745-6215-12-106).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica reading the Wittes paper you link, I understand what she calls a "non-inferiority" trial refers specifically to a trial that's designed with a non-inferiority margin and powered to test the hypothesis of non-inferiority, irrespective of the actual treatments assigned. My understanding is the same as Todd D. One can still test superiority in a trial where patients randomly receive investigational treatment vs usual care, even without blinding in fact.

Comment: @ToddD I would argue in your HIV trial, the argument for or against placebo has to do with participation bias, and ultimately the validity of the trial. This is ok if we mean ethics in a broader sense of policy and messaging, not a direct violation of the Helsinki declaration. I was moreover interested in the ethical treatment of patients in a trial.

Comment: @AdamO, if there's a condition for which there is an accepted, effective treatment, the IRB isn't usually going to let you test a new treatment vs placebo, because the placebo patients are untreated for the condition.  If you believe your new Tx is as good as the existing 1, you don't want to do a superiority trial, because you don't believe your Tx is superior.  You could do an equivalence trial, but it isn't a problem if yours turns out to be better.  So you just do a NI trial against the standard Tx. It doesn't have to be old + new Tx vs old + placebo, & it doesn't have to be equivalence.

Comment: If you look at Figure 2, you can see a range of outcomes are consistent with the hypothesis of non-inferiority, & good enough to move forward.  Defining & justifying the non-inferiority margin can be tricky, & there are special problems such as biocreep & assay insensitivity.  But the fact remains that you can just test new Tx vs existing Tx against a non-inferiority null when there is an accepted Tx.  This approach is not terribly common, but neither is it rare (104 published last year).

Comment: @AdamO For patients in a trial, ethics can get muddy. For a new treatment that shows benefit at an interim analysis, is it unethical to continue to administer placebo? Most trialists argue that equipoise still exists for placebo or usual care despite a potential benefit of active treatment; this stance is largely motivated by issues of false positives at interim analysis and the need to continue the study until a conclusive result is reached to value the efforts of those persons who remain enrolled in the trial.